# Split an object in to array of objects based on similar values

Tags: javascript

```
var pr = {
    name: "ball",
    race: "ball",
    weapon: "axe",
};

var save=new Object;
var keys=Object.keys(pr);

for(var k in pr) { 

}
console.log(save); // should end up with {name:'ball',race:'ball'}
```

Comment: What if there are multiple sets of the same values (like there is a second `axe`)?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood the question correctly, one option is:

```
const keys = Object.keys(pr);
const ret = keys.reduce((ret, k, i) => {
  const f = keys.find((k2, i2) => i !== i2 && pr[k] === pr[k2]);
  if (f) ret[k] = pr[k];
  return ret;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with.

```
var pr = {
  name: "ball",
  race: "ball",
  weapon: "axe"
};

const dupValues = Object.values(pr).reduce(
  (acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur]: (acc[cur] || 0) + 1 }),
  {}
);

const result = Object.keys(pr)
  .filter(key => dupValues[pr[key]] > 1)
  .reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr]: pr[curr] }), {});

console.log(result);
// {name:'ball',race:'ball'}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is use the `save` object as a histogram, keeping track of duplicates. Then, filter out any keys with 0 count using `reduce`. This should have better performance than a linear function like `find`:

```js
var pr = {
  name: "ball",
  race: "ball",
  weapon: "axe"
};
var save = {};

for (var k in pr) {
  save[pr[k]] = pr[k] in save ? save[pr[k]] + 1 : 0;
}

var result = Object.keys(pr).reduce((a, e) => {
  if (save[pr[e]]) { a[e] = pr[e]; }
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works. Simple and clear. References : [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Iterate through each key value pair, and accumulate the result until the loop ends.

```js
var pr = {
    name: "ball",
    race: "ball",
    weapon: "axe",
    item:"bat",
    newitem:"bat",
    newweapon: "axe"
};

var result = Object.keys(pr).reduce(function(acc, key){
    var ispresent = false;
    acc.forEach(function(obj,i){
        if(ispresent) return;
        if(Object.values(obj)[0]===pr[key])
        {
            obj[key]=pr[key];
            ispresent = true;
        }
    });
    if(!ispresent)
    {
        var newobj = {};newobj[key]=pr[key];
        acc.push(newobj)
    }
    return acc;
},[])

console.log(result)
```